# How do I add together multiple columns based on header names?

Tags: pandas

Here's what my dataframe looks like

```
Server  Performance123      Performance456                            
server1       1024             0
server2       110              0
server3       0                1024
```

Here's what I want it to ultimately look like

```
Server        Tier1
server1       1024
server2       110
server3       1024
```

Now obviously I could just add the two columns together but I can't be sure what the "123" or "456" part of the CSV I'm importing will look like as it's the last part of the UID of the datastore.

I've tried this

```
df['Tier 1'] = df.filter(like='Performance')
```

But I can't assign that as a new column in the dataframe. Any advice? I'm a bit of a newcomer to this so ran out of ideas quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after much searching and a lot of errors I have the below working code

```
df['Tier 1'] = df.groupby(df.columns.str.contains('Performance'),axis=1).sum()[1]
```